# How can I record system audio using python-sounddevice while using bluetooth earphones?

Tags: python, windows, audio, device-driver

I am using python-sounddevice to record system audio on Windows. Usually, I can use "(Realtek HD Audio Stereo input), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)" to get system sound.

But after connecting to my earphones via bluetooth, I can no more record the sound played by the system. All device python-sounddevices detected was listed below.

> 0 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input, MME (2 in, 0 out)
> 1 麦克风 (Realtek High Definition Au, MME (2 in, 0 out)
> 2 CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual , MME (2 in, 0 out)
> 3 Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable), MME (2 in, 0 out)
> 4 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output, MME (0 in, 2 out)
> 5 耳机 (1MORE ComfoBuds Pro Stereo), MME (0 in, 2 out)
> 6 扬声器 (Realtek High Definition Au, MME (0 in, 2 out)
> 7 Realtek Digital Output (Realtek, MME (0 in, 2 out)
> 8 Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable), MME (0 in, 2 out)
> 9 CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual C, MME (0 in, 2 out)
> 10 主声音捕获驱动程序, Windows DirectSound (2 in, 0 out)
> 11 麦克风 (Realtek High Definition Audio), Windows DirectSound (2 in, 0 out)
> 12 CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable), Windows DirectSound (2 in, 0 out)
> 13 Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable), Windows DirectSound (2 in, 0 out)
> 14 主声音驱动程序, Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
> 15 耳机 (1MORE ComfoBuds Pro Stereo), Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
> 16 扬声器 (Realtek High Definition Audio), Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
> 17 Realtek Digital Output (Realtek High Definition Audio), Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
> 18 Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable), Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
> 19 CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable), Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
> 20 扬声器 (Realtek High Definition Audio), Windows WASAPI (0 in, 2 out)
> 21 Realtek Digital Output (Realtek High Definition Audio), Windows WASAPI (0 in, 2 out)
> 22 Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable), Windows WASAPI (0 in, 2 out)
> 23 耳机 (1MORE ComfoBuds Pro Stereo), Windows WASAPI (0 in, 2 out)
> 24 CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable), Windows WASAPI (0 in, 2 out)
> 25 CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable), Windows WASAPI (2 in, 0 out)
> 26 Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable), Windows WASAPI (2 in, 0 out)
> 27 麦克风 (Realtek High Definition Audio), Windows WASAPI (2 in, 0 out)
> 28 线路 (), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)
> 29 Line Out (Virtual Cable 1), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 8 out)
> 30 Mic 1 (Virtual Cable 1), Windows WDM-KS (8 in, 0 out)
> 31 Line 1 (Virtual Cable 1), Windows WDM-KS (8 in, 0 out)
> 32 S/PDIF 1 (Virtual Cable 1), Windows WDM-KS (8 in, 0 out)
> 33 立体声混音 (Realtek HD Audio Stereo input), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)
> 34 Speakers (Realtek HD Audio output), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 2 out)
> 35 麦克风 (Realtek HD Audio Mic input), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)
> 36 SPDIF Out (Realtek HDA SPDIF Out), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 2 out)
> 37 CABLE Output (VB-Audio Point), Windows WDM-KS (8 in, 0 out)
> 38 Speakers (VB-Audio Point), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 8 out)
> 39 Output (@System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys,#4;%1 Hands-Free HF Audio%0
> ;(有一头老母猪)), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 1 out)
> 40 Input (@System32\drivers\bthhfenum.sys,#4;%1 Hands-Free HF Audio%0
> ;(有一头老母猪)), Windows WDM-KS (1 in, 0 out)
> 41 耳机 (), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 2 out)

I trys every devices, but I can't record system audio from any of them.

So how can I record system audio using python-sounddevice while using bluetooth earphones?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you need to setup a `virtual device` to record audio from an output.

I know you asked about doing this with `python-sounddevice`, but as an option take a look at [this fork of PyAudio](https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio). It adds the `PortAudio` libraries to `PyAudio` which will let you pick an output device and use it as an input (aka `loopback`).

[This example will show you how to use it.](https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio/blob/master/example/echo_python3.py). With it, on my machine I can use `Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)` as an input device.